# Changed Office365 password, cannot change in mail.app: account already exists

Tags: mail.app, email, office-365

- mac os 10.11.4
- mail app 9.3

Had a working **exchange/office365** account. Did not work anymore, used safari to go to office365.com and it appeared that I was required to change my password. So I changed it and can login on [www.office365.com](http://www.office365.com)
So the mail.app tells me to change the password, but when I hit save I get: *account already exists*.

So I removed the account from the `settings` --> `internet accounts`. closed mail.app, rebooted the mac and tried to add a new exchange account. But again "*account already exists*"

This seems similar to [Mac Mail - Account already exists error when adding gmail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/180785/mac-mail-account-already-exists-error-when-adding-gmail)
but iCloud is on a totally different mail account and even a different domain. 
Before I removed the exchange account, I manually updated all office365 passwords in the keychain. But that did not work either. Mail.app kept complaining.

Please do not suggest to move to outlook. I have outlook installed, but my boss (owner of the macbook) want to stick to the default mail.app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it.

- Went to ~/Library/Mail/V2
- opened the plist xml file in textwrangler
- removed all XML nodes containing the office365 accounts
- saved the file
- Went to ~/Library/Mail/V3
- deleted the folders related to the office365 accounts
- opened keychain app
- searched for `office`
- removed all entries related to the office365 accounts
- added the account at the settings -> internet accounts page

It works then. Strange that removing the account does not clear folders, and xml nodes in a settings file etc. and actually breaks re-adding the account. Perhaps someone can explain why this happened

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happen to me this evening after updating my Office365 password.

What worked for me was to open my desktop Outlook App and send myself a test email. Outlook was then prompted to ask me to put in the password. After adding the password to Outlook and sending the test email, I then went back to my Mac Mail and received my test email there. I also checked the Outbox in Mac Mail, which had three emails waiting to send. I double-clicked on the first one and then all three emails sent.

Comment: Thank you, but the question was 2 years old. I manually fixed it back in april '16. I think it's fixed in current versions.